# Full Definition Of A "Common Root"

Tags: typescript

Enumerations, modules and interfaces are merged if multiple blocks are defined within the same common root. I can't find an official definition of *common root* in the language specification.

Is it any more complicated than...

Either:

- The module, *or*
- The global scope

(The only complication I can think of is that if a module is merged, the members of all parts of the module being merged would then have the same common root, so it all zips up as you go).

Is there any other kind of common root?

```
module X {
    export interface Y {
        name: string;
    }
}

module X{
    export interface Y {
        age: number;
    }
}

// X.Y has both name and age properties
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a "common root" in the graph theory sense of the term, since any combination of TypeScript modules or programs forms a tree of declarations (because any declaration has exactly one parent). The second half of spec section 2.3 ("Declarations") defines exactly how that tree is constructed in terms of establishing parent relationships.

I think the relevant phrase in the spec here is that declarations merge if they have "the same qualified name relative to a common root". The simpler way to define this would have been "same fully-qualified name", but that wouldn't have handled the case where the declaration did not have a name that could be qualified from the global scope (e.g. an unexported interface inside a module).

The only other complication is when declarations exist in an external module, where the top level of the file is the external module itself rather than the global module:

```
export var x = 4;

/* Does not actually merge with the global 'Window', because
its parent is the external module */
interface Window {
}
```